# Make custom listview dialog look like standard dialog listview

Tags: android, listview, android-theme

I have a dialog with a listview, the first dialog is for selecting an item and the second one is when you edit the dialog. The first one uses a standard dialog box with no custom layout but for the second one I had to use a custom layout to get the picture in place (if anyone knows how I can populate a standard multiple choice dialog with an typed arrayadapter and item template let me know :)). The first dialog looks like standard dialog should look like but how can I get the second one to look the same with white background, lines between the items etc and be sure it always looks like the standard one even when that one is changed.

**Standard**
[image]
<sub>(source: [filedump.net](http://www.filedump.net/dumped/standard1320505506.png))</sub>

**Custom**
[image]
<sub>(source: [filedump.net](http://www.filedump.net/dumped/custom1320505506.png))</sub>

/Viktor

Answer (score 1):

For the same, you need to use **`setMultiChoiceItems`** while creating dialog. I hope this example helps you: [Android Multi selection dialogs](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/android-multi-selection-dialogs/)

And also check this example: [Android: Spinner-Like UI for Selecting Multiple Options](http://blog.chrisblunt.com/android-spinner-like-ui-for-selecting-multipl)

Comment: The problem is that with setMultiChoiceItems I can't provide a custom view and insert my icon that I need to have in the list for every item.